# Adding headers dynamically in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

For my android application, I'd like to allow the user to save multiple user profiles in the sharedpreferencies.
The app is for now able to store only one profile and I handled it from a PreferenceActivity with headers (one to store the user profile and one to store some app config) which are respectively linked to their dedicated PreferenceFragment.
My approach is now to create a new header called "Add profile", let the user save its datas in the PreferenceFragment and once he finishes by pushing the back button, update the PreferenceActivity's headers with the new created profile.

PreferenceActivity headers before adding

- Add Profile
- App config

After adding

- Profile 1
- Add Profile
- Remove Profile
- App Config

Does someone have an example for this?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far! As you know, this isn't a "do your work for you" site.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using an SQLite approach instead of sharedpreferencies.